# Xcode - Get Current date and time from a server(like time.is) and convert it to NSDate

Tags: ios, time

i don't want to get the current date from the users device, because the user can edit the date.

i would like to get the current date and time from a server like time.apple.com or time.is and then convert it to an NSDate. How?

Comment: Well, what have you tried?  Have you researched any API's, or even written any code at all?

Comment: no, no code yet. just want this NSDate from time.is or something

Answer (score 0):

You can first get the date in the form of a string by hitting the url (if the webservice is giving it as a string). And then using date formatter you could make the string into an `NSDate`.

For instance:

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://yourtimeurl"];
NSString *str = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url usedEncoding:Nil error:Nil];
```

assume you are getting the date in the format dd-MM-yyyy, then

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter.dateFormat =@"dd-MM-yyyy";
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:str];
```

But most probably when you hit your url, you might get some data structure like a json which you would have to parse. And most probably the date wouldn't be returned in the above format. But now you know how to go forward. Make the appropriate changes.

Also `initWithContentsOfURL:` is a synchronous call. It's recommended that you use a `NSURLConnection` for this and make asynch call to your webservice.

This might be useful: 
http://www.earthtools.org/webservices.htm#timezone  --xmlresponse
 
http://www.timeapi.org/utc/now --string